# Building a simple book reservation system

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Everything works fine and I am almost done, but would like to add a restriction regarding users age. To be specific, if a user tries to make a reservation for book that has a category of "Adults" (id=3), she/he should be at least 18 years old, otherwise validation error should occur.

Classes:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set;}

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }     
   
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public int Remaining { get; set; }
  
    public int Borrowed { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]        
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public string Available { get; set; }

    }


public class Lending
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Book")]
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }
   
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]     
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}


public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
   
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I have three categories in my database, Children(Id=1), Young(Id=2) and Adults(Id=3).

One of the ViewModels:

```
public class LendingViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Book")]
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public virtual Book Book { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }

    public string AvailableNow { get; set; }

    public int RemainingNow { get; set; }

}
```

Changes in IdentityModels:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

LendingController (just a part that is relevant):

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(LendingViewModel vm)
    {
        string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        vm.UserId = userId;

        var user = new ApplicationUser();
        user.Id = userId;
        var age = DateTime.Now.Year - user.BirthDate.Value.Year;

        var booksa = new Book();
        booksa.Id  = vm.BookId;        
                  
        if (ModelState.IsValid && vm != null)
        {
            if (age < 18 && booksa.CategoryId == 3)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "You are to young!");
                return View(vm);
            };
```

I also made necessary changes in RegisterViewModel and Register View. However, when a user that is younger than 18 selects a category with the id of 3 (Adults), she/he is still able to make a reservation for the book. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You've not set `booksa.CategoryId` as far as I can see.

Comment: Did this but still does not work:
            Category category = new Category();
            booksa.CategoryId = category.Id;

Comment: I suggest you move your business rules into a BusinessRules project. They're not the same thing as validation rules, which are really just things like validating required fields and whether EndDate is after StartDate, etc. Your business rules shouldn't live in your controllers.

Comment: i did that, unitofwork, repository...but to make this simplier, i showed it like this. Btw, I tend to put in repositories just those lines of code that refer to the database, is that correct? My viewmodels are always in controllers. Sorry for banal question, but I am a beginner.

Comment: Shouldn't your modification be something like `booksa.CategoryId = vm.CategoryId;`? Please run your debugger on the code and putting a breakpoint in the function and examining `vm` should yield useful information.

Comment: vm does not have property categoryId

Comment: it seems the problem is in identity models, I initialized birthdate to datetime.now, so when I try to calculate age it allways gives the value of null. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I used static method and combined it with the method from my repository. Here it is:

Repository:

```
 public bool BookForAdults(int bookId)
    {
        return db.Books.Where(b => b.Id == bookId).Any(b => 
b.CategoryId == 3);
    }
```

Extension:

```
public static int GetUserAge(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var db = ApplicationDbContext.Create();
      
        var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => 
u.UserName.Equals(identity.Name));

        return user.Age;
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(LendingViewModel vm)
    {            
        string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        vm.UserId = userId;

        var age = User.Identity.GetUserAge();

        var bookForAdults = 
        repo.BookForAdults(vm.BookId);

        if (ModelState.IsValid && vm != null)
        {
            if(age < 18 && bookForAdults)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "You are to 
young!");
                return View(vm);
            }
```